# Use libraries installed in Windows from WSL - Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-16.04, r, windows-10-v1703

I am using WSL - Ubuntu 16.04 in a Windows 10 computer.
I already got R and Rstudio installed on the main Windows 10 system.
Therefore, I was wondering if

1. it is possible to tell Ubuntu to use the R installed in windows?
2. does it make sense or it is too much complication compared to the easy way of just installing "another" R inside the Ubuntu distro?

My final aim is to submit simple scripts via `ssh`, and to my eyes, this is simpler from a UNIX environment than from Windows.

Comment: So you want WSL to launch a Windows application?  WSL has access to your Windows directories but it wouldn't know what to do with a Windows executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows version 1709 WSL can execute Windows .exe files.

Comment: But when I try the command R /home/folder/folder... R is not installed.

Comment: 1) Windows commands cannot access WSL files such as /home/folder/folder.

Comment: 2) WSL $PATH does not include directory where R is installed. 3) WSL does not automatically add ".exe" to file name. 4) WSL must access Windows files via the /mnt/c directory.

Comment: Thank you very much rhmccullough!! When i specify the whole path seems to work. If possible, I would like to make you to final questions if possible.
1) When I run the program, it ask me to add the command: `--save`, `--no-save`, or `vanilla`. What it is the difference among these.
2) Would it be possible to link the command R to the *.exe file?

Comment: 1) R --help lists all the options of the R command. 2) Yes. e.g.ln --help shows how to create a link. You might find it more convenient to create a shell script in your ~/bin directory.

Comment: @rhmccullough can your comments be added to the answer?

Comment: To Giulio Caccin: All my comments are available in the documentation of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have one update to my previous comments. 
Microsoft says that Windows programs can access WSL files in 2019. 
This feature is not yet available in my Windows version 1903 OS build 18362.86.